# PHP and SQL - How can I make this ID into a variable?

Tags: php, sql, variables, key, label

I am making a PHP website, and I want my user ID to load into the tickets table when you order a ticket. There is a webpage where you can select the ticket, the amount, and the ID is already given as a label.

The first code adds the data to my database

```
    function best(){
    global $db, $errors;

    // receive all input values from the form
    $ticket     = e($_POST['tickety']);
    $aantall    = e($_POST['aantal']);
    $usidd      = e($_POST['usid']);

    // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled
    if (empty($ticket)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Ticket is verplicht"); 
    }
    if (empty($aantall)) { 
        array_push($errors, "Aantal is verplicht"); 
    }

    // order ticket if there are no errors in the form
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
            $con = new PDO("mysql: host=localhost; dbname=website", "root", "");

            mysqli_query($db, $query);
            $_SESSION['success']  = "Ticket besteld";
            header('location: index.php');
            $query = "INSERT INTO tickety (ticket, aantal, userid) 
                      VALUES('$ticket', '$aantall', '$usidd')"; 
            mysqli_query($db, $query);


        }
    }
```

This code defines the input fields

```
<form method="post" action="ticketpag.php">

    <?php echo display_error(); ?>
    <div class="input_group">
        ID
        </br>
        <input type='hidden' name='usid'>
        <h4><?php
        echo $_SESSION['user']['id']; 
        ?></h4>
        </input>
        Ticket
        </br>
        <select name='tickety'>

            <?php
            $query = "SELECT * FROM `stok`";
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){                                                 
            echo "<option>".$row['naam']."</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        </br>
        Aantal
        </br>
        <select name="aantal">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
                <option value="15">15</option>
                <option value="16">16</option>
                <option value="17">17</option>
                <option value="18">18</option>
                <option value="19">19</option>
                <option value="20">20</option>
            </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn" name="bestel_btn"> Bestellen</button>
        &nbsp; <a href="index.php"> Terug</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where you have `input/textarea` with `name=usid`?

Comment: It's not a good practice to execute code after a redirect header (i.e. `header('location: index.php');` ). You should do everything you need to before this, and then `die();` afterwards to ensure the current page does not leak any data.

Comment: P.S. Why are you mixing `mysql_` and `mysqli_`? Don't. `mysql_` is dead, for a start. (see http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)

Comment: Its not about that, I want to fix this problem first

Comment: Please don't include garbage text just to bypass the filter, include more details.

Comment: @JopRill What do you see when you `echo $_SESSION['user']['id'];` inside of `best()`?  You should not be using `POST` to deliver existing `SESSION` data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add $_SESSION['user']['id']; to an input field instead of a label and it should work.

Example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="usid" id="usid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['id'];?>" />
```

Hidden fields are not shown to a user.

**Addition:**
But, as @mickmackusa mentioned, sending existing SESSION data using a POST request is a bad-practise. Instead test and see what happens when you echo $_SESSION['user']['id'] inside of best(). You should not be using POST to deliver existing SESSION data.

Comment: Which field would you advice?

Comment: This still doesnt give me a userid in my database

Comment: @JopRill What happens if you echo the $_SESSION['user']['id']; value to the browser? Does it show a value? And is the input field part of the from?

Comment: On the webpage it shows me the correct ID, but I think the name usid isnt linked to it or something, and I dont know How to fix it

Comment: @JopRill Could you please update your question and add the entire form to it? You have to make sure that the hidden input field is also part of your form.

Comment: @JopRill You're not setting a value in your code. Could you please replace the input field with my sample above? So replace:       <input type='hidden' name='usid'>
        <h4><?php
        echo $_SESSION['user']['id']; 
        ?></h4> with <input type="hidden" name="usid" id="usid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['id'];?>" />

Comment: @Yvo Why in the world would you advise that the OP send the id via POST when it is already being stored in SESSION?  Bad advice.

Comment: @JopRill You have received bad advice.

Comment: @mickmackusa Because he asked how to send it using a POST I assumed he's not able to retrieve it in the code for handling the form. 
If he's able to retrieve the SESSION in that code, then of course that's the better way.

Comment: It is important to steer inexperienced coders in the right direction, even if they aren't asking for it.  Why?  Because StackOverflow is not a one-to-one interaction.  This page will be viewed by thousands of future researchers and some will unknowingly copy-paste this bad practice.  For this reason, you should avoid indulging bad coding practices for the greater good.

Comment: @mickmackusa That makes sense. Thanks for your advise. So in this case it might be better to remove my answer?

Comment: You cannot remove an answer with a green tick on it.

Comment: @mickmackusa Mentioned you in my comment and added your suggestion ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind, but for now it works